# Programming language that doesn't require a runtime/dependency to be installed

Tags: c++, dependencies, runtime

I want to know a programming language that doesn't require a runtime/dependency to be installed on the target system. My primary target is Windows XP and above.

I tried Autohotkey but it dosent have many advance functions.

Firstly, please confirm that does 'C++' requires to install a runtime/dependency on the target system is is Win XP or later. Secondly, please suggest me an alternative to C++ that doesnt require a dependency to be installed.

**UPDATE**: I will be using CodeBlocks! Does the C++ code compiled with that requires a dependency?

**UPDATE**: Sorry for the misconception, by CodeBlocks I mean the default compiler of CodeBlocks (ie: `GNU GCC Compiler` or `MinGW`).

Comment: Visual c++ normally requires the libraries to be installed on the target machine, but you *can* package the DLLs with the built .exe file. You can also make a "static" build where the library functions are compiled into the .exe ittself. Either of those would perhaps work for you. (A comment only as I'm sure someone else can fill in how to do it with a proper answer)

Comment: Seems quite a strict requirement. Most programs have dependencies, why is yours different? What are you trying to do?

Comment: @PeterWood Most programs do depend on the OS being present, but there's no reason for them to depend on anything else.  You can link statically with everything but the OS, and there should be no dependencies.  (In fact, you _should_ link most libraries statically if you expect the code to run on a different system, which might have different, incompatible versions of the libraries.)

Answer (score 6):

Everything usually depends on the *project*, not the *language*. For example, programs compiled in Visual Studio's C++ uses some runtime libraries to work properly. However, you can configure the project in such way, that these libraries are included in the executable file, thus not needing additional dependencies. Delphi works similarly.

Here's the setting for Visual Studio Project:

[image]

If you choose option with "DLL", your program will require runtime DLLs. Otherwise it will be standalone, the runtimes will be incorporated into your binary file.

---

**Edit:** In response to question edit

I'll repeat myself: it depends on *project*, not the compiler or IDE.

Comment: It depends on the options passed to the linker.  With Visual Studios, these are specified in the project files; with most other systems, in makefiles.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a program that does not require anything else in order to run, except for base operating system (no .NET, no Java, no Perl, no runtime libraries, etc), then your best bet is to use `C` or `C++` and compile your program as single statically compiled executable.

It is rather difficult to achieve in practice, but it can be done.

Answer (score 0):

Codeblocks is not a compiler, but an IDE, that can use different compilers.
The most common one is **MinGW**.

To complie with minGW so that all the standard libraries are statically linked you shold configure your project (see "project settings") so the the linker options include the `-static` flag.

You can even be more specific by stecifying

```
-static-libgcc
-static-libstdc++
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your time, however the question wasn't so complex to answer.
Who want to inject executable with punch of DLL's & say this is a "stand alone" file that doesn't require runtimes!

My answer is that go for "**PureBasic**".
It's a low level language, but easy one, faster than C++, works directly with system and produce a very small exe which can run with OS files only (even in WinPE environment).

I encourage all to try & answer me if I'm wrong.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).